# IBInspectable UIEdgeInsets not shown in IBOutlet

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode7, xib, ibinspectable

I am creating a custom class for `UIButton` to increase the tap area. I need that user can enter the padding in storyboard itself. So I make a `IBInspectable` property.

```
@IBDesignable class UIIconButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var touchPadding:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

But it is not shown in storyboard. However if a replace the same with `CGRect` then it is visible in storyboard.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of Xcode 7, Interface Builder doesn't understand`UIEdgeInsetsZero` as an `@IBInspectable` (bummer!).

You can work around this, however, by using `CGFloat` properties to set edge insets indirectly:

```
public class UIIconButton: UIButton {

  @IBInspectable public var bottomInset: CGFloat {
    get { return touchPadding.bottom }
    set { touchPadding.bottom = newValue }
  }
  @IBInspectable public var leftInset: CGFloat {
    get { return touchPadding.left }
    set { touchPadding.left = newValue }
  }
  @IBInspectable public var rightInset: CGFloat {
    get { return touchPadding.right }
    set { touchPadding.right = newValue }
  }
  @IBInspectable public var topInset: CGFloat {
    get { return touchPadding.top }
    set { touchPadding.top = newValue }
  }

  public var touchPadding = UIEdgeInsetsZero    
}
```

This will correctly show the `bottomInset`, `leftInset`, etc within Interface builder.

Comment: Took me a couple of hours to get to this solution.